# How to split a CSV file into multiple files based on column value with header(not using AWK)

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have a CSV with invoice data - e.g.:
•Invoice #
•PO Ref
•Customer Code
•Customer Name
•Document Date
•Product Code
•Product Name

This CSV will have varying amounts of lines per invoice, which relate to invoice produt lines, which may span multiple invoice numbers.

I need to be able to run a batch file to look at this CSV and split off into multiple CSVs based on the value in Col A - Invoice and each file generate with header in the file.

Eg:

```
Invoice,PORef,CustomerCode,CustomerName,DocumentDate,ProductCode,ProductName
111222,PO123,C100000,Test Store,1/1/15,AB1000,Test Soft Toy
111222,PO123,C100000,Test Store,1/1/15,AB1001,Test Soft Toy1
111222,PO123,C100000,Test Store,1/1/15,AB1002,Test Soft Toy2
222111,PO321,C111000,My Store,1/10/15,AB1000,Test Soft Toy
222111,PO321,C111000,My Store,1/10/15,AB1001,Test Soft Toy1
222111,PO321,C111000,My Store,1/10/15,AB1002,Test Soft Toy2
```

The .bat should run and split the CSV into 2 separate CSV's:

CSV1:

```
Invoice,PORef,CustomerCode,CustomerName,DocumentDate,ProductCode,ProductName
111222,PO123,C100000,Test Store,1/1/15,AB1000,Test Soft Toy
111222,PO123,C100000,Test Store,1/1/15,AB1001,Test Soft Toy1
111222,PO123,C100000,Test Store,1/1/15,AB1002,Test Soft Toy2
```

CSV2:

```
Invoice,PORef,CustomerCode,CustomerName,DocumentDate,ProductCode,ProductName
222111,PO321,C111000,My Store,1/10/15,AB1000,Test Soft Toy
222111,PO321,C111000,My Store,1/10/15,AB1001,Test Soft Toy1
222111,PO321,C111000,My Store,1/10/15,AB1002,Test Soft Toy2
```

Getting software installed on my server is going to a hassle - as such, if there is anyway that this can be done without having to install software this would make me very happy.

I appreciate that there have been similar questions asked previously - however, I haven't been able to find out if there is another script I can run without installing Awk.

Regards Amol Murkute

Comment: Windows machine? Use a vbscript instead.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far and describe precisely where you are stuck! StackOverflow is not a free code writing service! Please learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Answer (score 1):

actually, that's quite easy with batch:

```
@echo off
set file=full.csv

REM get header:
<full.csv set /p header=

REM process file line by line (ignore header):
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,* delims=," %%a in (%file%) do (
  if not exist "%%a.csv" echo %header%>"%%a.csv"
  echo %%a,%%b>>"%%a.csv"
)
```

Split each line into two tokens (Invoice and "rest-of-line"). As name of your splitted files, you can use the invoice number.

Comment: @ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "destdir=u:\test"
MD "%destdir%" 2>nul
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d /o-d "%destdir%\NewsxpressInvoices_*.csv" ' ) DO (
  set "sourcefile=%%a"
  goto havefile)

:havefile
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (%destdir%\%sourcefile%) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1delims=," %%x IN ("%%a") DO (
 >>"%destdir%\inv%%x.csv" ECHO(%%a
 )
)

GOTO :EOF --Can u suggest changes in above code I would appreciate that. Thanks amol

Comment: You expect your csv to be in the newly created folder? hmmm... sure about that?

Comment: Yes I am sure. --Thanks

Comment: Above code giving me the CSV file which are generated without header I want to add header in each output file.

Comment: that's because you don't write the header. That's what `if not exist "%%a.csv" echo %header%>"%%a.csv"` does in my answer. (if the file does not yet exist, write the header)

Comment: One more question I am getting one more extra file which contain only header in the list and I don't want this file please tell me the solution for this as well.

Comment: the `skip=1` skips the first line (the header), so it isn't processed.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing CSV data correctly is not that trivial in batch scripting, so I decided I provide a solution, although you did not show any own research nor share any efforts.

Supposing that your CSV file does not contain any global wild-card characters `?` and `*`, the following code snippet might work for you (provide the CSV input file as command line argument):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "FILE=%~f1"
set "FSEP=_"
set "DSEP=,"
set "DCOL=Invoice"
set /A "NCOL=0"

if not defined FILE set "FILE=%~dpn0.csv"
if not defined FSEP set "FSEP=_"
if not defined DSEP set "DSEP=,"
set /A "NCOL+=0"

for %%F in ("%FILE%") do (
    set "FLAG=#"
    2> nul del /Q "%%~dpnF%FSEP%*%%~xF"
    for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%%~fF") do (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        set /A "CIDX=0"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem Double " characters:
        set "LINE=!LINE:"=""!^"
        set "LINE="!LINE:%DSEP%=","!""
        if defined FLAG (
            if defined DCOL (
                for %%I in (!LINE!) do (
                    endlocal
                    set /A "CIDX+=1"
                    if /I "%%~I"=="%DCOL%" set /A "NCOL=CIDX"
                    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                )
            )
            endlocal
            set "FLAG="
            set "HEAD=%%L"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        ) else (
            set "NAME="
            for %%I in (!LINE!) do (
                endlocal
                set /A "CIDX+=1"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                if !CIDX! EQU !NCOL! (
                    endlocal
                    set "NAME=%%~I"
                    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                )
            )
            if defined NAME (
                if not exist "%%~dpnF%FSEP%!NAME!%%~xF" (
                    > "%%~dpnF%FSEP%!NAME!%%~xF" (echo(!HEAD!)
                )
                >> "%%~dpnF%FSEP%!NAME!%%~xF" (echo(!LINE!)
            )
        )
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

The resulting output files are stored in the location of the input file and are named like the input file with the value of the dependent column appended (separated by `_`).

The column to regard for splitting the file may either be given by the column (header) name by the variable `DCOL`, or (if `DCOL` is empty/undefined) by the column number by the variable `NCOL`.

This script does not use `for /F` to get the field (cell) items but a standard `for` loop in order not to run into trouble with quoted items that contain separator characters on their own.